# The function needs to take in a string and using the alphabet variable and the histogram function to output missing letters alphabets in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a function called `missing_letters` that takes in a string as an argument and loops over it to see which letters of the alphabets are missing in the input string. The function needs to return the missing letters in alphabetical order. The function should make use of the `histogram` function.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

The histogram function I need to use is:

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1
    return d
```

I tried to input a string of `'hello'` in the function and tried to print the missing letters but it seems like my loops are not correctly working.

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1
    return d


def missing_letters(string):
    global alphabet
    h = histogram(string)
    missing = []

    for k in alphabet:
        for l in h:
            if l not in k:
                missing.append(l)
    return missing


print(missing_letters('hello'))
```

If I pass `aaa` as an argument to the function, the output should be like `aaa` is missing letters `bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

My output is something like `['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'........]`

Comment: Is this not a one-liner, something like `[char for char in alphabet if char not in histogram(string)]`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but that may call ```histogram(string)``` 26 times.

Answer (score 2):

`if l not in k`

`k` is a letter of the alphabet.

`missing.append(l)` You're appending the letter that *does* exist in the histogram to a list of the letters that *don't* exist in the histogram.

```py
def missing_letters(string):

  global alphabet
  h = histogram(string)
  missing = []

  for letter in alphabet:
    if letter not in h:
      missing.append(letter)

  return missing
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have not seen the error, the code output the right result now.